# Indexed table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am a beginner in Swift, I have tried to make an `Indexed table view` according to this tutorial: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/indexed-table-view-ios-tutorial-ios11, but I have some doubts and I would like to ask something. Here is my code so far:

```
 for car in cars {
        let carKey = String(car.prefix(1))
            if var carValues = carsDictionary[carKey] {
                carValues.append(car)
                carsDictionary[carKey] = carValues
            } else {
                carsDictionary[carKey] = [car]
            }
    }

    // 2
    carSectionTitles = [String](carsDictionary.keys)
    carSectionTitles = carSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

First of all, I want to make a sure that this line

```
if var carValues = carsDictionary[carKey]
```

takes all cars starting with word(carKey) from `carsDictionary` and store to array. If it is true, it stores the next car to the array, and put it back into the dictionary. Is it correct?

Unfortunately I don't understand what this line is doing

```
carSectionTitles = [String](carsDictionary.keys)
```

Also, I'm not sure about this function, mainly with the section "configure the cell"

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // 3
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let carKey = carSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let carValues = carsDictionary[carKey] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = carValues[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Does it work like a loop? I am not sure about `indexPath.section`. Could someone explain it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That’s a lot of questions, you’re supposed to ask one at a time. Since you’re new with Swift I would recommend reading [this on-line Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/) to better understand the language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to create the dictionary is correct but in Swift 4 there is a much more convenient way

```
carsDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: cars, by: {$0.prefix(1)})
```

The line `carSectionTitles = [String](carsDictionary.keys)` creates an array of the dictionary keys (the prefix letters). This line and the next line to sort the array can be written in a more efficient way:

```
carSectionTitles = carsDictionary.keys.sorted()
```

`IndexPath` has two components, `section` and `row`. The sections are represented by `carSectionTitles` and the keys in the dictionary and the rows are the values in the dictionary. `cellForRowAt` is called once for each row. The code gets the section from `carSectionTitles` and gets the rows from the dictionary. The optional binding is actually not needed because it's guaranteed that each letter has an associated array.

```
let carKey = carSectionTitles[indexPath.section] // carKey is one of the prefix letters
let carValues = carsDictionary[carKey]! // get the rows
cell.textLabel?.text = carValues[indexPath.row] // get the value for that particular row
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question, how I need to modify your line with creating Dictionary, if I have array of classes (car) and there is string with car name?